# Как построить график используя колонки таблицы?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, визуализация, seaborn

У меня есть вот такая таблица где 1-ая колонка - сторона света. Остальные колонки - месяца. А значения - некая абстрактная численная величина.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'side of the world': ['север', 'юг', 'запад', 'восток'],
    'jan': [44, 55, 607, 11],
    'feb' : [46, 60, 384, 84],
    'mar' : [51, 70, 398, 99],
    'apr' : [47, 11, 582, 70]
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять каким образом я могу построить график по этой таблице. Пытался используя seaborn сделать lineplot который будет отображать 4 линии - каждая из которых показывает изменение численной величины по месяцам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), предварительно преобразовав исходный фрейм (при необходимости). В данном примере создан индекс из первого столбца для формирования надписей оси и фрейм транспонирован, чтобы по оси Х были месяцы, а по Y - значения для сторон света.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'side of the world': ['север', 'юг', 'запад', 'восток'],
    'jan': [44, 55, 607, 11],
    'feb': [46, 60, 384, 84],
    'mar': [51, 70, 398, 99],
    'apr': [47, 11, 582, 70]
})

df.set_index('side of the world').T.plot(kind='bar') # можно попробовать другие типы графиков, меняя аргумент kind (см. документацию)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]